# SQLAlchemy mapping case statements into model fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to map two boolean values that I get after executing a query with a case statement.
My models are the following:

```
class Account(Base, SerializableMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    followers = relationship(
        'Account', secondary='followers_followees',
         primaryjoin=(FollowAssociation.followee_id == id),
         secondaryjoin=(FollowAssociation.follower_id == id),
         backref='followees')

class FollowAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'followers_followees'

    follower_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('accounts.id'), primary_key=True)
    followee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('accounts.id'), primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

And my query looks like:

```
with session_scope() as s:
    ali = aliased(FollowAssociation)
    s.query(Account, case([ (FollowAssociation.follower_id == None, False) ], else_=True),
        case([ (ali.follower_id == None, False) ], else_=True))\
     .outerjoin(FollowAssociation, and_(Account.id == FollowAssociation.followee_id, FollowAssociation.follower_id == 1))\
     .outerjoin(ali, and_(Account.id == ali.follower_id, ali.followee_id == 1)).all()
```

And I get results like:
     `(<rsh.accounts.models.Account object at 0x7fe350477990>, False, False)`

Is there any way to map these two boolean values that represent if an account is followed by another in my model? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very common in sqlalchemy but possible. There are several ways to do so.
One of them is construct custom mapper instance.

```
query = session.query(
    Account,
    case([(FollowAssociation.follower_id == None, False)], else_=True).label('first'),
    case([(ali.follower_id == None, False)], else_=True).label('second')
).outerjoin(
    FollowAssociation,
    and_(Account.id == FollowAssociation.followee_id, FollowAssociation.follower_id == 1)
).outerjoin(ali, and_(Account.id == ali.follower_id, ali.followee_id == 1))


class CustomAccount(object):
    pass


mapper(CustomAccount, query.statement.alias())

res = session.query(CustomAccount).all()
print(res[0].id)
print(res[0].first)
```

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8352659/) full example. 
Other possible way is using [hybrid_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property).

Comment: Great, this is just what I wanted.